# Contract that converts ERC20 token into a new ERC223 according to specific exchange rate

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, erc-223

I did some research but I couldn't find anything so specific. I would like users that own a specific ERC20 token to be able to use it to buy an ERC223 token generated by a contract according to specific exchange rate. The ERC20 token should then get stuck in the contract and nobody should be able to withdraw it. Basically we want to convert 1000 old ERC20 tokens into 1 ERC223 new tokens. Thanks.

Comment: There is no question here, just an implementation requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1) A person would have to grant the new ERRC223 contract an `allowance` via the `approve()` function call of your ERC20 token.

2) The new ERC223 contract would have a function callable by the same account that granted the allowance. This function would use `transferFrom()` of the old ERC20 contract to transfer the balance from the `tx.origin` (the OG `msg.sender`) to itself (`address(this)`).

3) Within the same transaction as step #2: the new ERC223 contract would then calculate the exchange ratio and mint/transfer the appropriate about of new tokens to the account.

Comment: Thanks, how do I implement this in a contract?

Comment: These functions are part of the ERC20 standard. Any smart contract developer would be able to implement this. For a new developer, a simple Google query will go a long way to providing your answer.

Comment: Well, thanks for telling me to find it out myself.

Comment: You gave 0 code to your question. You asked a simple question. I gave you the correct way, via text, on how to solve your problem. Querying on the key function names in my response would result in everything you need to learn about how to implement it. If you need someone to implement it for you, I suggest hiring a solidity developer.